# Redirect request to different Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a button in Layout page, which is supposed to navigate between different views.

```
<a id="next" href="/Navigation?CurrentPage=@ViewBag.CurrentPage">Next</a>
```

I populate `ViewBag.CurrentPage` value in ViewModel of each page.

Navigation controller intercepts anchor click in following controller -

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    public void Index(string CurrentPage)
    {
        PageType currentPageEnum = (PageType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PageType), CurrentPage);
        PageType nextPageEnum = currentPageEnum + 1;
        RedirectToAction(nextPageEnum.ToString());            
    }
}
```

Enum contains ActionNames in sequential order, so just increment currentPageEnum value to find next page.

```
enum PageType
{
    Page1,
    Page2
}
```

Each action has a mapping route in Global.asax.cs as below -

```
routes.MapRoute("Page1", "Page1", new { controller="controller1", action="Page1"});
routes.MapRoute("Page2", "Page2", new { controller="controller2", action="Page2"});
```

**Question:**
I have not been able to redirect to other controllers with this code-

```
RedirectToAction(nextPageEnum.ToString());
```

Request terminates without redirect.

1. What info am I missing.
2. Is there a better efficient way to navigate
       between diffrent views, in ASP MVC

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a return statement and make the function return something.

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string CurrentPage)
    {
        PageType currentPageEnum = (PageType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PageType), CurrentPage);
        PageType nextPageEnum = currentPageEnum + 1;
        return RedirectToAction(nextPageEnum.ToString());            
    }
}
```

And since you refer to a mapped route name and not an action I believe you need `RedirectToRoute` instead of `RedirectToAction` like in this code:

```
public class NavigationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string CurrentPage)
    {
        PageType currentPageEnum = (PageType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PageType), CurrentPage);
        PageType nextPageEnum = currentPageEnum + 1;
        return RedirectToRoute(nextPageEnum.ToString());            
    }
}
```

But I would suggest that the best way to navigate in an MVC environment from the (razor)view is like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName)
</div>
```

If the action is in the same controller. If not use this overload:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Is this approach, the best one to implement navigation in MVC.

Comment: @autrevo I added the best way to navigate from the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an efficient way as below:

just use

```
   RedirectToAction("ACTION_NAME", "Controller_NAME");
```